# SQL subqueries to get field's value as a field name on the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table, what i want to achive is to get some rows of the `detail_key` column as column name and the `detail_value` as the actual row.

```
Table places

detail_key | detail_value
--------------------------
location   | Athens
country    | Greece
longtitude | 12,3333
weather    | good
```

I have tried the query below below but only works for 1 field each time.

```
SELECT detail_value AS location FROM places  WHERE detail_key= 'location';
```

The result  i want to achieve is this below:

```
location   | country | longtitude
-----------|---------|-------------
 Athens    |Greece   |12,3333
```

Comment: What is your common field?  Without something to pivot on there is not a way to do what you are asking...

Comment: There is not a relation with another table, i just want to take some rows from the `detail_key` column as field names and their `detail_values` as the row. The query in my post works fine, in other words i need something like another 2 of almoast the same query all combined

Comment: @Makis is there any reason for you to do this directly on MySQL? Or can you use a front end (e.g. PHP, Python, Java, etc)? "Transposing data" can be quite a pain with pure SQL

Comment: You just want to pivot, take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: @Barranka Thanks for all your answers. I was asked to do it by sql, so i have to find the related query..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a cross table.

MySQL does not include a built-in function for cross tables, but you can build your cross table query "by hand".

**Important:** You must have a key to group the data. I'll assume that you have a `place_id` column:

```
select max(case detail_key when 'location' then detail_value end) as location
     , max(case detail_key when 'country' then detail_value end) as country
     -- and so on
from places
-- add any WHERE conditions here
group by place_id
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Edit

Your comment made me rethink your problem, and I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns). Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a variable that holds the expressions you want to apply to get what you need
2. Create a valid SQL query
3. Use a prepared statement when your query is ready.

I created a little [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f2d/4) for you to see how to solve this, and here it is:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f2d/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table places(
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  place_id int,
  detail_key varchar(50),
  detail_value varchar(50)
);

insert into places (place_id, detail_key, detail_value) values
(1, 'location','Athens'),(1,'country','Greece'),(1,'longitude','12.3333'),(1,'weather','good');
```

**Query 1**:

```
set @sql = null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f2d/4/0)**: (No results)

**Query 2**:

```
select group_concat(distinct
                    concat(
                      "max(case detail_key when '",
                      detail_key,
                      "' then detail_value end) as `",
                      detail_key,
                      "`"
                    )
       )
into @sql
from places
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f2d/4/1)**: (No results)

**Query 3**:

```
set @sql = concat("select place_id, ", @sql, " from places group by place_id")
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f2d/4/2)**: (No results)

**Query 4**:

```
prepare stmt from @sql
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f2d/4/3)**: (No results)

**Query 5**:

```
execute stmt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f2d/4/4)**:

```
| place_id | location | country | longitude | weather |
|----------|----------|---------|-----------|---------|
|        1 |   Athens |  Greece |   12.3333 |    good |
```

---

### Final edit

If you somehow created the above table with the data corresponding to just one place (i.e. there's no `place_id` and all details are from a single place), you can do something like this:

```
select max(case detail_key when 'location' then detail_value end) as location
     , max(case detail_key when 'country' then detail_value end) as country
     -- and so on
from places
-- add any WHERE conditions here
group by null;
```

Comment: @Makis Great! I edited my answer to include a working example, including a way for you to avoid creating the expressions "by hand" and let MySQL create the full SQL query